# Report Builder PrintToFile Types

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, reportbuilder

I have a question about Report Builder as we are using it for our reporting purposes.

In the Print Preview screen there is a printer icon on the left top corner. Clicking on it opens the Print dialog where there is "Print to File" option. In that option you can select the Type (PDF File, XLS Report File, etc.). My question is: "Is there any possibility to know at run type which Type user has selected?". In other words I need to know whether he selected "PDF File" or "XLS Report File" or something else?

I tried to catch the ppReport.DeviceType property at the ppReportBeforePrint event but it shows 'Printer' for ALL types of export.

I attached the screenshot of the Print dialog for better understanding.

We are using Delphi XE3 + Report Builder 15.03 under Windows 8.1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To separate the export type you can use the code below:

```
procedure TForm1.ppReport1BeforePrint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ppReport1.DeviceType = 'Screen' then
    // Preview Report on the Screen
  else if ppReport1.DeviceType = 'Printer' then
  begin
    if (ppReport1.FileDevice is TppXLSReportDevice) then
      // Export to Excel
    else if (ppReport1.FileDevice is TppPDFDevice) then
      // Export to PDF
  end;
end;
```

To get the printer button enabled on the preview screen use:

```
ppReport1.AllowPrintToFile := True;
```